# Estimate of Taylor coefficients

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, analytic-functions

I have a real function f(x) different from zero and not proportional to $\exp(x)$ analytic at origin, $$ f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}c_n x^n,\ \forall x:|x|<\delta $$
To derive a result, I should require that $\forall n\geq N$ $$|c_n|\leq \frac{A}{n!} $$
with $A$ being a constant $\geq 0.$   Which hypothesis should I give to $f(x)$ to have  that $|c_n|\leq \frac{A}{n!}$?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the $c_n$'s allowed to be negative?

Comment: Yes, but I have edited my question, the request is about $|c_n|$

Comment: What is the question ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust As I said, which hypothesis should I have for f(x) 
f(x) to satisfy this request?

Comment: Which "request" ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust As I said, the request that $|c_n| \leq \frac{A}{n!}$. Is that clear now?

Comment: Do you mean "what is a condition on the entire function $f$ required for its coefficients to be bounded by $A/n!$ ?" Necessary, sufficient ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sufficient

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is sufficient. $f(x)=Ae^x$ is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that since $c_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$, if you require that there exists some constant $A$ such that for any $n$, $|f^{(n)}(0)|\leq A$, then your condition can be obtained.